# How do I get the coordinates of every integer point inside a polygon, given only the vertices of the polygon?

Tags: python, polygon, vertices

I need to create an image containing a convex polygon, given only the vertices of the polygon. Therefore, I need to find which of the pixels in the image would lie inside the polygon, and colour them differently.

I thought about casting rays from each pixel to count the line intersections and deduce whether the pixel is inside a polygon or not, but this would take a long time to run for hundreds of pixels.

How can I do this more efficiently? I am using Python, with PIL to create the image.

Comment: You can find the min and max of the x and y of each vertex to bound the problem to a finite set of pixels to test.  Then, I wonder if this will tell you how to test each pixel:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon

Comment: With [`ImageDraw.polygon(xy, fill=None, outline=None)`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html) you can specify the border color `outline` and the fill color `fill`.